# Отправка сообщения vk через xmlhttprequest не используя vk api (отправить прямо со страницы)

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, xmlhttprequest

Задался целью исследовать и, по возможности, использовать некоторые встроенные функции движка vk.com, такие как отправка сообщений, нажатие на лайк, некоторые операции с аудио, и тому подобное. Обязательное условие, не использовать vk api, т.е. действия должны быть сымитированы, как будто я использую стандартный механизм через интерфейс сайта.

Начал с самого простого, отловил XMLHttpRequest на отправку сообщения и вытащил хедеры. После чего написал небольшую функцию и запустил в консоли.

```
function go() {
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var q = 'Message=^&act=a_send_box^&ajax=1^&al=1^&chas=a01dfe4bd253a6c2f7^&from=box^&media=wall211592748_35^&title=^&to_ids=211592748';
    r.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (r.readyState == 4) {
            if (r.status >= 200 && r.status < 300) {
                alert('done');
                } else { 
                alert('fail');
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        r.open('POST', '/al_im.php', true);
        } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }

    r.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    r.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    r.send(q);
    return r;
}

go();
```

Запрос ушёл, в ответ пришёл статус 200, done и блок текста. Но сообщение не отправилось.

Тогда я нажал Replay XHR, для того, чтобы браузер самостоятельно повторил запрос, и после этого сообщение ушло.

Не понимаю, в чём может быть проблема.

Если у кого-нибудь есть идеи или наработки, то буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Сообщение точно не отправилось? Если вызвать ваш код, а затем обновить страницу, сообщения нет?

Comment: Точно, нет. Более того, видимо vk использует long polling так как в случае с Replay XHR я сразу же без обновления страницы вижу, что сообщение приходит.

Comment: "отправить прямо со страницы" С какой страницы? CORS не слышали?  "Если у кого-нибудь есть идеи или наработки" то бесплатно он их не отдаст ,вещь скоропортящаяся, денег для поддержки всегда мало

Comment: @koshkashoshka, интересует лишь наработка возможности отправить запрос. Наработка функционала не нужна. Ответил в комментариях к первому ответу: отправляю с той же самой страницы vk, так что это один и тот же домен. CORS применимы лишь когда шлёшь с другого сайта, правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Во первых - когда вы делаете XMLHttpRequest в vk, то ваши куки из соседней вкладки с авторизованным vk не отправляются в vk. Во вторых ajax между разными доменами по-умолчанию запрещён.

Так устроен ajax. Почему "по умолчанию" ajax между разными доменами не разрешить: в таком случае любой сайт можно было бы превратить в "армию роботов", которые совершают от IP-адреса пользователя без его ведома использование чужих сайтов - не относящихся никак к исходной площадке.

Сначала причины запрета были более весомы - как защита от XSS, от кражи паролей: вообще нельзя было слать ajax между разными доменами, а затем ввели CORS заголовок: например с домена vasya-pupkin.pru шлётся запрос на vk.com, и если vk.com в ответе вернул CORS заголовок - то vasya-pupkin.pru получает тело этого запроса, а иначе: нет. vk.com сам решает - разрешить себя читать с помощью ajax, или нет.

Объяснил подробнее - потому что надобность кросс-доменных ограничений при ajax на сегодняшний день не слишком очевидна. А вообще куки через cross-ajax всё равно не утащить, а то что запрос ajax-ом и он сторонний, сервер и так понять может: поэтому эти ограничения, как и CORS, возможно скоро уйдут из web-стандарта.

> т.е. действия должны быть сымитированы

Тем не менее имитацию можно сделать. Но только посредством сервера, и только передав своему серверу в запросе данные для аутентификации (чужие данные вы при этом не сможете взять, так как доступ между окнами разных доменов будет заблокирован - отправка сообщения в ВК, это же iframe) - ваш сервер может от своего IP может безгранично слать запросы куда-угодно. Так вот вы делаете на сервере прокси (вручную, на PHP, например это делается с `curl`) - отправляете запрос на свой сервер, а он уже проксирует его на vk.com .

> и запустил в консоли.

То, о чём говорилось выше - это о запуске кода при открытии web-страницы. В консоли, а так-же в других плагинах браузеров: может быть своя логика(и свои баги), так как там ограничений практически нет.

Comment: Да, я наталкивался на пару статей, где объясняли, что в данном случае мешает CORS. Конечно, может я немного не понимаю логику этих ограничений, но мне всегда казалось, что домен то один и тот же. Находясь на странице vk.com/* я шлю запрос на vk.com/*, так что какие тут должны быть проблемы? Или в качестве домена-отправителя, в этом случае, выступает мой IP-адрес, а не vk.com?

Comment: Что касается куки и авторизационных данных, то в том числе я пробовал отправлять куку `r.setRequestHeader('Cookie', document.cookie);`, но это не помогло.

Comment: `то в том числе я пробовал отправлять куку ` конечно не помогло, потому что у iframe-а своя кука, к которой нет доступа из родительского документа, а `document.cookie` - совсем другая кука. Если бы доступ был - представьте, от имени пользователя можно было бы совершать деятельность на любом портале - такие дыры закрыли ещё в 95м году .

Comment: `Находясь на странице vk.com/* я шлю запрос на vk.com/*, так что какие тут должны быть проблемы? Или в качестве домена-отправителя, в этом случае, выступает мой IP-адрес, а не vk.com?` в таком случае, да, должен быть vk.com .  Ну вы тогда лучше симулируйте ajax, а следом симулируйте клик, и сравните отправленные запросы: что-то упустили, какой-то заголовочек/параметр/CSRF-токен - что-то такое